# AttributeError: 'User' object has no attribute 'joined_at' [discord.py]

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I am using this code to get a date when a user joined the server

```py
if answers['member_older'] != None:
      for i in range (len(id)):
        x = id[i]
        account_memb = client.get_user(x)
        print(account_memb)
        joined = account_memb.joined_at
        new_date_memb = datetime.today() - joined
        member_old = new_date_memb.days
        if member_old < answers["member_older"]:
          users.pop(users.index(account_memb))
          print(users)
```

but for some reason it is showing an attribute error

```
Task exception was never retrieved
future: <Task finished name='Task-56' coro=<_create.<locals>.start() done, defined at d:\Giveaway Bot\main.py:412> exception=AttributeError("'User' object has no attribute 'joined_at'")>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:\Giveaway Bot\main.py", line 477, in start
    joined = account_memb.joined_at
AttributeError: 'User' object has no attribute 'joined_at'
```

I'm using a similar code to get a date when the user's account was created and it is working perfectly

```py
    if answers['acc_older'] != None:
      for i in range (len(id)):
        n = id[i]
        account =  client.get_user(n)
        created_at = account.created_at
        new_date = datetime.today() - created_at
        old_days = new_date.days
        if old_days < answers['acc_older']:
          users.pop(users.index(account))
          print(users)
```

Comment: Please provide the rest of your code, that if statement and it's body, is it in a function ? what is the id variable, etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`joined_at` is an attribute of the `Member` object, not `User` object. I think you'll need to change up your code to get a member instead for this piece of code to work.

[discord.py documentation for getting members](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=get%20member#discord.Guild.get_member)

Comment: but how do I get discord.Membed with user's id?

Comment: ```account_memb = discord.Guild.get_member(user_id=x)``` , I have tried this , but now it is showing ```TypeError: get_member() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'```

Comment: You will need to use an actual guild object in order to get members. Also, you don't put `user_id=x`, just input `x`. For example, `account_memb = ctx.message.guild.get_member(x)` would be valid in this case.